# How to switch New Composition Settings Duration from Base 25 (time) to Frames?

Tags: after-effects

In the tutorial I am doing the instructor has their Composition Settings enabling them to input the amount of Frames they would like the Composition to be. Picture is a little faded, it says "Frames @ 24 fps"

[image http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-1.png](http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-1.png)

Now my Composition Settings only allow me to set in time.

[image http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-2.png](http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-2.png)

How can I set in Frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, this has to be done in the composition window itself.  In the top left-hand corner of your timeline window, you know the little orange numbers that tell you the current timecode?  If you CMD + click on that (ctrl + click on windows), it'll switch to Frames instead of timecode.

When you hit CMD + K to bring up the composition settings again, you'll see that Duration and the other relevant categories are now shown as Frames instead of timecode.

Note that this will shift your *whole* timeline to Frames (including the markers on the timeline itself), which you may or may not want.  If you just want to have it for frames while you're editing the composition settings, though, you can always just CMD + click on the number in the upper lefthand corner of the timeline to switch it back to timecode.